# variable not working for animating scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to calculate how far down the screen to scroll. I do this by calculating the pixels from the top window. This is my code:

```
$('#nav_ibutton_start').click(function(){
header = $('#header_wrapper').offset().top;
element = $('#ibutton_products').offset().top;
pos = header-element;
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: pos }, "slow");
});
```

I have alerted the 'pos' variable and it is the correct number. And I have tested it without a variable, e.g.:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 500 }, "slow");
```

And it works fine also. Why does it not work when I am using the 'pos' variable?

Answer (score 0):

your result is in Negative.this is not possible that scroll will go top(because it is already on top position).

and your code will work only if you down the scroll and then click on `#nav_ibutton_start`

i modified your code.check below

```
var pos = header-element;(your value is -)
```

just change order to `var pos = element-header;`

```
$('#nav_ibutton_start').click(function(){
header = $('#header_wrapper').offset().top;
element = $('#ibutton_products').offset().top;
var pos = element-header;
    alert(pos);
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: pos });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CWC7u/1/

Comment: Oh you are right! Don't know how I managed that. Also realised that I actually wanted header = $('#header_wrapper').height();